# How to get $(n+1)!(n+2) = (n+2)!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I mean it makes sense when I look at it that the two are equal, but I don't entirely understand *how* you get from one to the other - I presume there's some basic algebra involved - but I'm not sure what it is, how to figure it out, could someone explain this concept to me? I understand it somewhat relates to telescopic series, but I feel like if I don't understand this basic concept, I won't really get the rest of it.

Comment: This is false unless I am missing something...

Comment: @TomCruise I edited the question and took off the "- 1" on the end, so now it makes more sense.

Comment: but $(n+1)!(n+2)=(n+2)!$

Comment: @TomCruise You're right. I guess I should probably stop studying for the night lol

Comment: By definition $(n+2)!$ is the product of all whole numbers from 1 up to $n+2$.  Well, $(n+1)!$ gives you the product of all whole numbers from 1 up to $n+1$...so multiplying by $(n+2)$ gives you $(n+2)!$...

Answer (score 3):

$$(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!=(n+2-1)\cdot(n+1)!=(n+2)\cdot(n+1)!-(n+1)!=?$$

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this is different than the OP's desired identity of:
$$(n+1)\cdot (n+1)! = (n+2)! - 1$$
- but that's probably for the better, since that's false.

Comment: @Meelo yeah, I actually just corrected that in my title - I was doing an induction problem and they jumped from the LHS of the title to the RHS, and I couldn't figure out how they did it.

Comment: @Meelo, Has there been any change in the Question?

Comment: You lost me around $(n+2−1) \cdot (n+1)!=(n+2) \cdot (n+1)!−(n+1)! $ What did you do with the -1 within $(n+2-1)$?

Comment: @TaiM., Now $(n+2)\cdot(n+1)!=(n+2)!$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:-**

$n!=1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot n$

But your expression is false, it should be $(n+2)(n+1)!=(n+2)!$.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from here - since n! is the product of all numbers up to n, then (n+1)! is the product of all numbers up to n *plus* n+1, then you multiply (n+2), giving you the product of all numbers up to n *plus* n+1 *plus* n+2 so you essentially are doing the same as if you were doing (n+2)!

Gotcha.

Comment: @TaiM.: Brilliant. I think you should write a proof of your own.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Part of the definition of factorial is $$n!=(n-1)!\times n$$

Answer (score -1):

(n+2)!=(n+1)!(n+2)

(n+1)!((n+1)+1)=(n+2)!

(n+1)!(n+1)+(n+1)!=(n+2)!

(n+1)!(n+1)=(n+2)!-(n+1)!

hmmm..... where was i wrong on this?!
Edits:
(n+1)!(n+1)=(n+1)!(n+2)-(n+1)!

(n+1)!(n+1)=(n+1)!(n+1)

hmmm.... yah.

also: the fixed title: lets say n=3, then (3+1)!(3+2)=(3+2)!

(3+1)!=1*2*3*4

(3+2)=5

(3+2)!=1*2*3*4*5
get it?